# aligning equations in latex

Tags: latex

I have the following code in an attempt to align things in latex using amsmath package:

```
\begin{alignat}{3}
\text{max}  && c^Tx &=\\
\text{s.t.} && Ax &\leq  b \\
        && x    &\geq  0
\end{alignat}
```

Basically, i would like for max and s.t. to be in one column, c^Tx, Ax, x to be in second column, and lastly b and 0 to be in the last column. I'm not sure why it doesn't work (it clumps max and c^Tx together for some reason.

if anyone can help me out with this it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With math-mode `\text{}` you should put in some explicit whitespace such as `\quad`. But `max` smells like a log-like symbol so you should be using pre-defined `\max` or self-defined `\operatorname{max}` instead of `\text{max}`.

Additionally, the parameter for the `alignat` environment should be `2` in this case. The param is the number of alignment structures and can be calculated by solving `n` from `a=2n-1` where `a` is the number of ampersands on a row. However, it doesn't seem to have a difference in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! \quad works very nicely. The equation is for standard inequality form for linear programming problem statement. It is basically saying maxmize {equation} subject to the conditions below. Normally I should use \max, but in this case it wouldn't look as "normal"

Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening here is that `max` and `s.t.` are being right-aligned, which is running them right up next to `c^Tx` and `Ax`. If you just add some whitespace to the right-hand-side of `max` and `s.t.`, you should be in business.

(Also, laalto is right, you should definitely use `\operatorname{max}` if max is some sort of operator or function. Though I'm not really sure what you're doing, so maybe it isn't.)